# Remove namespace from class in java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, processing, alias

I have created a Processing sketch in IDEA, and am using multiple files. However, in the second file, none of the Processing methods are defined, so I found a trick:

```
...
public static PApplet processing
public void setup () {
    processing = this;
    ...
}
...
```

and I can access the methods in the other class by calling `Main.processing.*` (the main class is called 'Main') and I can use the methods just fine.

I'd like to know how I can get away without having to type `Main.processing....` every time i want to make a function call, is there a way to alias all of the functions so that I can call them as usual? `point(...)` rather than `Main.processing.point(...)`?

Comment: Why not write a method named `point(...)` who's sole purpose is to call `Main.processing.point(...)` and return the value?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want to achieve with your code.  Could you posta more complete example? 

Just so I'm sure i understand what you are trying to do. You store _this_ in a static instance variable of PApplet. And PApplet has a method Point. 

Static import should do most of the trick depending on if Point is static or not. 

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html

simply do 
 import static Main.processing;

Comment: static import worked for the most part, I have found that using `import static Main.Main.*;` has imported all the static fields that I was using, except the processing functions or any functions I have declared in the main class.

Comment: If you're looking to use PApplet static methods (such as sin(), lerp(), map(), etc.) `import static processing.core.PApplet.*;` is probably best. If you're looking to access non-static methods & fields, (like ellipse(), frameCount, etc.), then Kevin Workman's answer is best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the other questions are missing the context that you're using Processing, which has its own quirks.

But generally, what you'll want to do is pass your sketch instance into any non-PApplet class. Here's an example:

```
public class MySketch extends PApplet{

  MyOtherClass myOtherClass;

  void setup(){
    myOtherClass = new MyOtherClass(this);
  }

  void draw(){
    myOtherClass.drawCircle();
  }
}

public class MyOtherClass{
  PApplet sketch;

  public MyOtherClass(PApplet sketch){
    this.sketch = sketch;
  }

  void drawCircle(){
    sketch.ellipse(100, 100, 100, 100);
  }
}
```

This class uses the `this` keyword to pass a reference to the top-level `PApplet` class into the `MyOtherClass` constructor. The constructor stores the reference in a variable, which it can now use to access Processing's functions.

There isn't a clean way to alias the functions so you can call them directly, and imho most of the other answers are a bit hacky. You should definitely **not** use the `static` keyword for this, as that's abusing the purpose of what `static` is meant for.

I would stick with the straightforward approach of using a reference to the sketch. If it really bothers you, maybe name it `s` so it's only two extra characters `s.` for each function call?

Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/java/processing-in-java) is a guide on using Processing as a Java library, including the above approach.

Comment: as it turned out, this was the approach I ended up going with, it seemed that there was indeed no official way to alias the functions. Thank you for your clear answer. this solved my issue. (as best as possible)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access instance methods, save the enclosing object in a variable.

If you want to access class methods, use **static imports**:

> A single-static-import declaration imports all accessible static
>   members with a given simple name from a type. This makes these static
>   members available under their simple name in the class and interface
>   declarations of the compilation unit in which the single-static-import declaration appears.

([Chapter 7.5.3. Single-Static-Import Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html)).

Answer (score 0):

To be able to understand and to make as it should be done in a right way, i think you should firstly understand the encapsulation in Java development:
public, private, protected, package(none), and all other field descriptors.
I think a good start will be here:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm 
OR
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

EDIT 1: A simple example, of course there are more cases in tutorials and documentation, and is also valid for methods:

```
    public class A{ //"your.package.A.java"

        private int a; // Only accesible from class A, but is an instance field  :  a = 0; Only from class A
        private static int aS; // Only accesible from class A, but is a static field, one value shared to all objects of type A : aS = 0; only from class A;
        protected int aP; //  Accesible from class A or any subclasses that A can have : aP = 0; OR super.aP = 0;   
        public int aPublic; // Accessible from any class that has imported package: "your.package" : A instance = new A(); instance.aPublic = 0;
        public static int aSPublic; // // Accessible from any class that has imported package: "your.package" via class name, one value shared per all accessors : A.aSPublic = 0;
        int aPackage; // Accessible from any class that is in the same package with A and not fdrom other packages, EX: clas B, but only via instance: A instance = new A(); instance.aPackage = 0;
        int static aSPackage; // Accessible from any class that is in the same package with A by class name: A.aSPackage = 0;
    }

    public class B{ //"your.package.B.java"

    }
```

Comment: I do understand this concept, and am quite familiar with it, I am just wondering if there is a way to alias the functions.

Comment: in java you don't alias the function to call them out of nowhere. you call them from a class instance.

Comment: From what i saw in your question, i think you do not really understand what means static fields/methods, and class(object) fileds/methods, this why i leaved few links to start.

Comment: You can do this is C++ and in C# to some extent, so I guessed you could do this in Java too.

Comment: you can do many things with many languages, that doesn't mean every language can do the same things

Comment: You don't need namespaces in Java, you have packages. So when you import that package you have access to all classes in that package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Java Reflection** to get `Method` object(s) for method(s) you want to invoke.
Instantiate this (/these) `Method` object(s) and use it (/them) in this class.

Refer: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/methods.html

Answer (score -3):

You could put them inside a function:

```
public void point(...) {
    Main.processing.point(...);
}
```

Although im not sure if thats good practice...

If Main.processing is an object you could also save it in a variable (with a short name).

Comment: It seems this is the only option, this just means that I have to do this for every method that I use. that's a lot.

Comment: If you have to do that for every method you use, you probably have a huge design problem

Comment: I originally started this project in the Processing editor, where everything would automatically be namespaced.

Comment: I have to agree with @jhamon, you should consider reworking your code if you run into problems of these kind.

Comment: `function` is no defined keyword in java

Comment: Oh, sorry, i am mixing languages